# Can images be combined using the clip CSS Property while still maintaining image SEO and semantics?

Tags: seo, html, css, images, performance

I have two images in my web page. Actually there are 20 but I want to keep things simple:

```
<div>
    <img src="apple.png" alt="Apple" />
    <img src="orange.png" alt="Orange" />   
</div>
```

Those two images depict different fruits. But I want to decrease server hits and I want to combine those 2 images into 1 single image as `fruits.png`

And by using [Clip property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) I want to assign suitable fruit image to the related `img` tag by the help of `class` attribute and `css` rules.

But resulting code looks like below.

```
<div>
    <img src="fruits.png" alt="Apple" class="apple_image" />
    <img src="fruits.png" alt="Orange" class="orange_image" />  
</div>
```

Although first `img` tag's `alt` attribute says as "Apple", the `src` attribute points to `fruits.png` which is not an apple image.

I want to ask, does this usage break semantics of the web? Can Google Image search robot give penalty for such kind of usage? Does this kind of usage affect SEO of my web site?

Or if there is any other method, what is the best solution to handle images while keeping hits low and preserving the SEO quality?

Comment: Its misuse of the ALT tag and will effect your accessibility score. Your alt tags should a description what the image is about, its one or the other but not both with the method you mention. Use CSS sprites for combing elements and use standalone images for actual images, with actual ALT tag usage. Your server-side requests should be reduced by combing of CSS, JavaScript and other non-element types. The best solution to handle images by serving them on a content delivery network, trying to combine images will be a waste of time,  never mind loss of traffic from Google image search.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Simon. But even with CDN, 20 images block other page assets to download because browsers only download 4 item at a time for a specific domain.So I thought to combine them and use Clip to reduce hits and prevent blocking. What do you think? BTW, I could not understand CSS sprite thing. Is not CSS Sprite and Clip same for my task? Plus CSS Sprite works as background-image, I suppose which will make me replace all img tags with div tags, I suppose.

Comment: `Only download 4 item at a time`, not true. It's actually 6 for Firefox, Safari and Chrome, and 13 on IE11... and these numbers are doubled when using a CDN... 6 becomes 12, 13 becomes 26... CSS sprites are for UI elements, they are better than clip as they have better support. As I said, you shouldn't be combining photos, its pointless and sucks for accessibility. If your pages are heavy on pictures then you could use lazyload.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thank you again. Is there any restriction on CDN number please that can be added for a domain? If I specify CDN for each specific asset, does browser increase simultaneous download? Say `css-cdn.example.com`, `img-cdn.example.com` and `js-cdn.example.com`.

Comment: Just like your website a sub domain or external domain are subject to DNS resolve and server first byte. Using a good CDN you won't notice much if any improvement from using 2 CDN's due to the factors I've mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much Simon for your help. I have also 10 navigation links that are iconic like this: `<a><img></a>`. Do you think it is wise to remove `img` elements and set the images by `background-image` css property for the very anchor, maybe even with CSS Sprites? Of course anchor elements needs to be `display:block`. Does changing display property of anchor tags affect SEO and Semantics?

Comment: Menus are not considered content. Google and other search engines do not pay much attention to menus and other template based elements. You should use CSS sprites.

Comment: Oh I see. But how do search engines differentiate menus from content please? I can use `<a><img></a>` template for both menus and the content images. Or do I need to provide some kind of hint for the search engine?

Comment: Google works contents areas within their algorithm, for example menus are repeated on every page.. these are automatically detected, but other factors include width of the menus and the content, It's rather complex and your need to do research :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37072/discussion-between-john-sewell-and-simon-hayter).